# How to make child TextViews stay in position in Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

Here I have a `RelativeLayout` with `TextViews`, `Spinners` ect. The `TextViews` change according to the progress value of the respective `Spinner`. I want my `TextViews` to remain in the current position and not shift the match the length of the growing parents progress value.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Space
    android:id="@+id/Space1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Space
    android:id="@+id/Space2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Space1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/primaryneedsbg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
    android:text="@string/housing"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    android:includeFontPadding="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="@string/debt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:includeFontPadding="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/child"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:includeFontPadding="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/edu"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/exp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/special"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/surv"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="176dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginRight="219dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button04"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button06"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button05"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button06"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:background="@null"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar1" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar04"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar03"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SeekBar04"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SeekBar04"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SeekBar03"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SeekBar02"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SeekBar02"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView13" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button06"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/SeekBar01"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/SeekBar01" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button04"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button12"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button07"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button08"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button08"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button09"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button09"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SeekBar02"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button11"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="+"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView07"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button12"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView07"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/SeekBar03"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button10"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView05"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView04"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageView03"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button16"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SeekBar03"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button18"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button17"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/SeekBar04"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button15"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button14"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button15"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button05"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="Temporary" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button23"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button17"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button17"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button21"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button14"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button15"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button24"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button18"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button22"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Button21"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button16"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button20"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button14"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button14"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button21"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button19"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Button13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button13"
    android:text="@string/Perm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button03"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button25"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/SeekBar03"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button07"
    android:text="@string/permNeeds"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/tempNeeds"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/tNeeds:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView14"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
    android:text="$0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="@string/typeNeed"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/lifebar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/lifebar4"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: There are many textViews in this layout, which one is talking about? I think you'd better upload an image.

Comment: You forgot the `RelativeLayout` closing tag.

Comment: Could you please explain what is really happening?